# Is this the right way to cancel form submit in 2020?

Tags: javascript

I need to cancel HTML form submits with Javascript when inputs are invalid. In olden days, all I have to do is trigger `form.submit()` and then `event.preventDefault()` to do so, but I found this doesn't prevent actual form submits anymore. Instead, I found the code below works as I intended. Is this really the right way to cancel form submits in 2020?

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button type="button">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    const theForm = document.querySelector('form');
    const theButton = document.querySelector('button');
    theButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // I thought this would work
        //theForm.submit();

        // This does work
        theForm.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {
            cancelable: true // this option is required for only Firefox
        }));
    });
    theForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('do some pre-submit stuff');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In 2020, we don't use JS to validate forms any more. Form validation is done with HTML attributes on the inputs. Things like `maxlength`, `type="email"`, `required`...

Comment: Handling submit button click events instead of form submit events is a pet peeve of mine (mainly because you can submit forms with the keyboard). Simply do your validation in the submit handler and use `e.preventDefault()` if anything fails. Not applicable to async validation though